# How to get attribute name and its value properly?

Tags: html, xslt

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Software>
    <MS version="5.2.3.1"/>
    <Java version="5.1.0.29" />
    <Oracle id="A" version="1.0.1.11" />
    <SQL id="P" version="1.0.1.11" />  
</Software>
```

XSLT:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[1]">
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//*">
        <tr>
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> ::
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

**Current output [wrong]:**

This script gives output without column name
"id". Some "version" column value added in "id(not visible)" column as
there is no attribute name id in node. eg. MS node has version
attribute only hence output result added version info in "id" column.
Please go through output once, possibly save and check in html for proper understanding.

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td/>
    <td>
      <td>version</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Software ::
              </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MS ::
              <td>5.2.3.1</td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Java ::
              <td>5.1.0.29</td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oracle ::
              <td>A</td><td>1.0.1.11</td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SQL ::
              <td>P</td><td>1.0.1.11</td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Expected output:**

Every attribute as columnname/header and all column
have their own value. NOTE: Attributes MS, JAVA, etc as column Name
should not be hard coded because the number of attributes may change on runtime.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td/>
    <td>
        id<td>version</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MS ::</td>
              <td>Not exist</td><td>5.2.3.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Java ::</td>
              <td>Not exist</td><td>5.1.0.29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oracle ::</td>
              <td>A</td><td>1.0.1.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SQL ::</td>
              <td>P</td><td>1.0.1.11</td>
  </tr>
</table>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a full (that is, working) XSLT stylesheet. Also, it makes more sense to actually _show code_ when describing output - otherwise it can be hard to follow.

Comment: Mathias, I have changed xslt and also added output. Please save output in html and check which is easy to understand.In result I am expecting two column name id(currently not visible as first node has not attribute name id) and version. Value MS:: 5.2.3.1 is version but in result it comes under id column not version column. I want id value under id column and version value under version column. Please  no hard coded name for columns, it should be generated at runtime.

Comment: XSLT aside, you're putting `<td>`'s inside `<td>`s. That's not valid HTML.

Comment: Flynn, Yes format is incorrect but result is expected, Please try it here http://www.xslfiddle.net/ Just copy/paste xml and xslt code here and check result.Save this result in html to understand my question properly.

Comment: @Sam, could you fix those nested td's?  It's easier to debug when syntax is correct.

Comment: I have fixed nested td. Output I am looking for added in expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to output one column for each possible attribute name, and not restrict it to just **id** and **version**, then (in XSLT 1.0) you could make use of a technique called Muenchian Grouping to get the distinct attribute names.

First define a key to look up the attributes by their name

```
<xsl:key name="columns" match="@*" use="local-name()" />
```

Then, to get the distinct ones (or rather, get the first occurrence of each distinct name), you can define a variable like so

```
<xsl:variable name="columns" select="//@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('columns', local-name())[1])]" />
```

Then, to output the column headers, you can just iterate over this variable

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
     <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
     <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

For each row, you would take a similar approach. Assuming you were positioned on a child element, you could first define a variable that contains the attributes of the current element. Then you would iterate over the **columns** variable again, and output the value of the corresponding attribute for the current element

```
  <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="@*" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
     <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
     <td><xsl:value-of select="$attributes[local-name() = local-name(current())]" /></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="columns" match="@*" use="local-name()" />
   <xsl:variable name="columns" select="//@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('columns', local-name())[1])]" />
   <xsl:template match="Software">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td>Software</td>
      <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
         <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
         <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Software/*">
      <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
      <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="@*" />
      <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
         <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$attributes[local-name() = local-name(current())]" /></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Software</td>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>version</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MS</td>
    <td/>
    <td>5.2.3.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Java</td>
    <td/>
    <td>5.1.0.29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oracle</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1.0.1.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SQL</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1.0.1.11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note, for brevity, I have not included code to output "Not exists" in the case where the attribute does not exist. But it should be simple enough to add a check for this. (Just store the value in a variable, and use an **xsl:choose**)

EDIT: If you want to restrict the attributes to specifically be for **Software** elements too, try changing the key to this:

```
<xsl:key name="columns" match="Software/*/@*" use="local-name()" />
```

Comment: Hi, I tried ur code but it will add other nodes attribute as column even though match=software but it is adding hardware too. Check xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Directory> 
    <Software>
        <MS version="5.2.3.1"/>
        <Java version="5.1.0.29" />
        <Oracle id="A" version="1.0.1.11" />
        <SQL id="P" version="1.0.1.11" />  
     </Software>
    <Hardware>
        <hd1 a1="5.2.3.1"/>
        <hd2 a1="5.1.0.29" />
        <hd3 a1="A" v1="1.0.1.11" />
        <hd3 a1="P" v2="1.0.1.11" />  
     </Hardware>  
</Directory>

Comment: I've made an edit at the end of my answer to explain how to do this.

Comment: Thanks tim, I was trying <xsl:key name="columns" match="Software/@*" use="local-name()" /> but its wrong.

Comment: How can I show every directory information separately using same template. is there any change here <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />  see xml <root>
  <Directory>
    <Software>
      <MS version="5.2.3.1"/>
      <Java version="5.1.0.29" />
      <Oracle id="A" version="1.0.1.11" />
      <SQL id="P" version="1.0.1.11" />
    </Software> 
  </Directory>
  <Directory>
    <Software>
      <MS version="5.2.3.1"/>
      <Java version="5.1.0.29" />
      <Oracle id="A" version="1.0.1.11" />
      <SQL id="P" version="1.0.1.11" />
    </Software>
</Directory>
  ..........
</root>

Comment: I think it is best you ask a whole new question, rather than asking it via comments, as this is getting slightly more complicated than was originally asked. As a hint though, you will probably need to replace all occurrences of "Software" with "Directory/*"

Comment: Tim, I have added question please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993824/how-to-use-template-for-multiple-but-same-section

Answer (score 0):

Hummm, I have tried to fix the HTML issue and the problem you are facing.
This is a bit mannual, but can achieve your requirement. **Here is the XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>id</td>
                <xsl:for-each select="//*[1]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="//*">
                <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> ::</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>Not Exist</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:if test="@version"><xsl:value-of select="@version"/></xsl:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Here is the output of it:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td/>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>version</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MS ::</td>
    <td>Not Exist</td>
    <td>5.2.3.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Java ::</td>
    <td>Not Exist</td>
    <td>5.1.0.29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oracle ::</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1.0.1.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SQL ::</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1.0.1.11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tested it on http://www.xslfiddle.net/

Comment: id and version should not be hardcoded, it will change/generate at runtime. Please check below answer by Tim c