# How to use template for multiple but same section?

Tags: xml, xslt

My question is related with link [How to get attribute name and its value properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973974/how-to-get-attribute-name-and-its-value-properly/20979490?noredirect=1#comment31544380_20979490) As per Tim suggestion I am raising this question separately. I want to show every directory information separately. Current XSLT file shows result for one directory. So what changes should I make such same template will use for all directory and shows every directory information separately, please check xml file.

I have tried with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="directory/*" />
```

and many other option but not got result.

Input XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <root>
      <Directory name="1">
        <Software>
          <MS version="5.2.3.1"/>
          <Java version="5.1.0.29" />
          <Oracle id="A" version="1.0.1.11" />
          <SQL id="P" version="1.0.1.11" />
        </Software> 
      </Directory>
      <Directory name="2">
        <Software>
          <MS version="5.2.3.1"/>
          <Java version="5.1.0.29" />
          <Oracle id="A" version="1.0.1.11" />
          <SQL id="P" version="1.0.1.11" />
        </Software>
      </Directory>
      <Directory name="3">
        <Software>
          <MS version="5.2.3.1"/>
          <Java version="5.1.0.29" />
          <Oracle id="A" version="1.0.1.11" />
          <SQL id="P" version="1.0.1.11" />
        </Software>
      </Directory>
      ..........
    </root>
```

XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="columns" match="@*" use="local-name()" />
  <xsl:variable name="columns" select="//@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('columns', local-name())[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Directory">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Software</td>
          <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
      </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Software/*">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
      </td>
      <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="@*" />
      <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$attributes[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
        </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You could just do for-each for directory elements on root level.

Comment: it is giving same section value repeatedly if u use for-each.

Comment: Er, this is working fine as far as I can see. 3 tables are produced. What's wrong?

Comment: Please give us an example of what you want the result to look like. Your transform does currently output each directory's own values.

Comment: Yes, Zyga is right.For-each is solution for this problem.

Comment: How to mark it as answer?